# Binding a GridView to a List

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I am having the worst time figuring this out. I have to use MVVM which I do not completely understand yet and bind a list filled with data from SQL to a radGridView. Sounds easy enough... but I cannot figure it out. The data is not displaying and I think it is because I am binding it wrong. Below is my relevant code. Any help would be appreciated!

C# (HistoryAuditLogViewModel.cs):

```
  #region Private Fields

        private DatabaseConnectionSetting dbSetting;
        private string tableName = "Manufacturers";
        private int primaryKeyID = 1;
        private string entryID;
        private string manufacturerID;
        private string manufacturerName;
        private string auditDate;
        private string sqlLogin;
        private string application;


        private string dbConnectionKey = Alliance.Infrastructure.Common.DatabaseConnectionSetting.BACKFLOW_SCOPE_KEY;

        #endregion

 public void Load_Audit()
        {
            string strSQLconnection = (dbSetting.SqlConnectionString + "; User Id = " + dbSetting.SqlUserName + "; Password = " + dbSetting.SqlPassword + ";");
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection); 

            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT [EntryID], [AuditValue].value('(row/@ManufacturerID)[1]', 'int') as ManufacturerID, [AuditValue] .value('(row/@ManufacturerName)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as ManufacturerName, [AuditDate], [SqlLogin], [Application] from [Backflow].[dbo].[AuditLog] where (TableName = @tableName AND [EntryID] = @primarykey)", sqlConnection);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tablename", tableName);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@primarykey", primaryKeyID);

            SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();



            List<String> dataList = new List<String>();


            while (reader.Read())
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    string rdr = reader[i].ToString();

                    dataList.Add(rdr);
                }
        }
```

XAML (HistoryAuditLogView.xaml):

```
 <telerik:RadGridView Name="AuditGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding dataList}">

        </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Comment: Be sure to set `DataContext` property of your `View` to your `ViewModel`. offtopic: dont forget to close `sqlConnection`

Comment: Your `while`loop seems strange. Do you want flatten your table to list?

Comment: It probably is strange haha but, no. Basically I am not picky about how this needs to be done. I just have to use MVVM and put the data from sql into a datagrid. @Nogard thank you for reminding me to close the connection and I have the DataContext property set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full public property may help you, add it at root level of your `ViewModel`:

```
#region Private Fields
...
#region
#region Public Props

private List<String> _dataList;
public List<String> dataList 
{
get{ return _datalist;}
set{_datalist = value;}
}

#region


public void Load_Audit()
        {
dataList = new List<String>(); //then your code
//.... 
}
```

Comment: Never know before you try - but should.

Comment: Alright it is binding correctly. This is probably because I am using a list and flattening it as Hamlet said but instead of the data going across each column in the gridView, it is shown going down the rows. Any quick fixes? Or should do I need to create a separate question?

Comment: sure there is - change your `List<string>` to `List<YourClass>` and populate it correctly. `DataGridView` should catch the rest

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> dataList = new List<String>();
```

It's just a local variable, accessible and valid only within that method. You have to move it into property or field:

```
public List<String> DataList { get; set; }
```

and within the method:

```
DataList= new List<String>();

while (reader.Read())
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        string rdr = reader[i].ToString();
        DataList.Add(rdr);
    }
```

Comment: So like a get or set? I updated my question to include more of my VeiwModel code.

Answer (score 1):

MVVM Bindings work with Public Properties in your ViewModel...

Further, it's also better to bind to Observable Collections if possible.

For this, you would need to use the following code;

```
private ObservableCollection<String> _DataList;
public ObservableCollection<String> DataList {
    get { return _DataList; }
    set {
        if (value.Equals(_Details) == false) {
                 _DataList= value;
                  OnPropertyChanged("DataList");
        }
    }
}
```

The `OnPropertyChanged` Sub raises the `INotifiyPropertyChanged` event, so that any changes to the Collection are automatically reflected in your GridView.

You would need to create this sub, however if you wanted to, you could raise this event directly in the Setter.

Your Code would then be;

```
_Details = new ObserservableCollection<string>();

while (reader.Read())
   for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
   {
       string rdr = reader[i].ToString();
       dataList.Add(rdr);
   }
```

Your XAML would remain the same as you have above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the DataContext when you Initialize the View an the viewModel

```
MyView view = new MyView();
MyViewModel viewModelodel = new MyViewModel();

view.DataContext = viewModel;
```

An other solution would be to set the DataContex in your View.
But you have to tell your View the ViewModels location.

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" >
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

Of course you have to add a public Property which represents your list in your ViewModel.